# post message to facebook news feed

Tags: php, facebook, feed

I am running an ecommerce website in php. When facebook connected users make a search or post a sale, I want it to automatically post messages to the user's facebook news feed. I wonder how i could do it? any articles I can read about?

Thanks,

Comment: There are a lot of questions about this here in SO, also I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-a-message-on-the-user-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/33/) about it yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to take publish_stream permission from user. Read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)